# Could the initial d- in the word for tongue be originally a prefix?

Tags: morphology, comparative-linguistics, sound-change, proto-world

I am looking for the most ancient proto-world lemmas and it seems, the word for tongue is shared by many families from over the world. Here are some selected examples:

```
Niger-Congo:
* Proto-Heiban:       d̪ingәla / ringәla
* Proto-Talodi:       t̪ulenge / ləlenge
* Proto-Katloid:      -langed
* Rashad:             tangela-k / yangela-k

Eurasiatic:
* PIE:                dn̥ǵʰwéh₂s
* Manchu:             ilenggu

* Burushaski:         yuŋus

Arauacanian:
* Mapucho:            ðungu (language)

* Haida (Alaska):     tʼāngal

Sahul & Indo-Pacific:
* Proto-Nyulnyulan:   d-yangala
* Proto-Pama-Nyungan: dyalang
* Bunuban:            djälän
* Tiwi:               tingawa (lip), yunguk (language)
* Proto-Gunwinyguan:  thelng
```

These examples suggest possible reconstructions as `dyungala/lingala`.

But what we know is that in Proto-Heiban and Proto-Talodi, `d-/r-` and `t-/l-` are prefixes, [meaning](https://www.academia.edu/27625214/Do_Heiban_and_Talodi_form_a_genetic_group_and_how_are_they_related_to_Niger-Congo) "long objects or domestic animals". In Proto-Nyulnyulan `d-yangala`, `d` is also a prefix, giving reflexes with and without it. In some other languages presence of the initial stop changes the meaning, such as in Tiwi `tingawa` (lip) versus `yunguk` (language).

So, I wonder, whether these two forms could persist into PIE?

We know, that the split exists in PIE as well: Germanic `tongue`, Latin `lingua` and `dingua`, Baltic `liežùvis` and `insuwis`, Armenian `lezu`. The change `d->l` has been explained by influence from the word for "lick", but could it be the case that PIE inherited in fact the both forms, with initial `d-` and with initial `l-`?

Comment: Wouldn't we expect to see initial *l- in some Indo-European forms, then, outside of Latin? (Some people attribute the alternation in Latin between initial d and l to Etruscan; there's not a ton of evidence but it's a nice theory. Either way we don't really see it outside of Latin.)

Comment: @Draconis we do have. As you can see from the question, we have Lithuanian `liežùvis`, Armenian `lezu`, both inherited from PIE.

Comment: Yeah, I realized addressing that would take more than a comment, so I turned it into an answer; see below.

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely. Almost all of the descendants of **dn̥ǵʰwéh₂s* (a truly wonderful mess of diacritics, that) show a dental consonant at the beginning; the main ones that don't are Latin and Armenian, and both of those conveniently have a word for "lick" that has a very similar shape (Latin *lingua* and *lingere*, Armenian *lezu* and *lizem*). In fact, while Balto-Slavic lost the initial dental completely, we later see an *l* get inserted there in dialectal forms (e.g. apparently some Russian dialects use *l'azyk* for standard *jazyk*). Since it would be *extremely* difficult for this **l* to survive all the way into Russian without leaving any traces along the way, it's almost certain that it's an innovation within Russian.

Some linguists have also attributed this Latin d~l alternation to Etruscan, which shows confusion between initial *d* and *l* in various words; since our knowledge of Etruscan is limited, there's not a ton of evidence for it (and contamination from *lingere* is more likely), but it's a fun theory. And if it's correct, it would explain *littera* and *laurus* from Greek *diphthera* and *daphnē*.

Comment: Also, Lithuanian liežùvis...

Comment: What I see, is overwhelming evidence that this word comes from much more depth than PIE. One cannot Just explain similarities between Indo-Pacific `d-yangala`, Haida (Alaska) `tʼāngal`, and Niger-Kongo `d̪-ingәla`. Thus, I am convinced that even if at PIE stage we had only d-, it was originally a suffix alteration.

Comment: Notice also Manchu `ilenggu`, which is considered Eurasiatic, and has l-.

Comment: @Anixx have you considered sound symbolism to explain the similarities you observe?

Comment: @Keelan do you mean onomatopoeia?

Comment: @Anixx onomatopoeia are a type of sound symbolism. I'm not suggesting tongues make *l* and *ng*-sounds. However, *ng* is a consonant where you can show someone your tongue quite well. And *l* is used for flexible objects and motions in many words, so there is some relation there as well. I'm not saying that either of these two is necessarily correct. I only want to show that there are reasonable explanations for these parallels other than shared ancestry or language contact. And as long as the parallels are confined to one lexeme, such an alternative may be the simpler explanation.

Comment: @Keelan the listed languages also exhibit similarities in other lexemes as well. Recently I was antonished by the similarity of Haida language to the rest. For instance, its word for "language" is "kil" which is another widespread root to mean tongue or language (Finno-Ugric keeli, Mongol hel, etc), often reconstructed for Nostratic. Its word for "winter" is snagg, Its second-person singular pronoun is dā, its word for "pair" is xādā (PIE kʷeth₂, Samoyed kitä, FU ket-, Omok kit, Mapuche ka, Burushaski kaat). Its word for one is sgwān, also very similar.

Comment: @Anixx do you have regular sound correspondences for these? You say “often reconstructed for Nostratic”, but I’d say most people think there is not enough evidence for Nostratic.

Comment: @Keelan Nostratists and those who studies Eurasiatic definitely have proposed regular sound correspondensies, but I think at this depth this method of establishing correspondencies is largely useless. Of course, if we could firmly establish ones, it would be great, but the distance between the lannguages is too far. Yet, the similarity of some glosses across the families cannot be just a coincidence. Roots like "neyla" for "four", "kel" for language, in Eurasiatic, pronouns, interrogatives, cannot be just coincidence. We cannot rule out borrowings though.

Comment: @Anixx I’m not saying it’s a coincidence, I’m saying that sound symbolism is another option that should not be discounted.

Comment: @Keelan if this is a common sound symbolysm for tongue, then why there are *two* absolutely different common roots for tongue, *dyungala and *kelx?

Comment: @Anixx this is not uncommon; animal sounds also differ cross-linguistically, for example.